# Page is not properly redirecting with express-session and passport nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am using passport-local and express-session but my problem is that when I enter an address, after I close the session, I get the problem the browser "Page is not properly redirecting", so what I want to do is redirect to The address / login instead of showing that problem

I'll leave my code

Routes.js

```
app.get('/index', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session);
        if (req.session == null  || req.session == undefined)
        {
             res.redirect('/login');
        }
        else
        {
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    }

    });
```

app.js

```
 app.use(session({
     secret  : 'asjdknas',

 }));


 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(passport.session());
 app.use(flash());
```

update solved

The verification I did the function I was calling in app.get call

Function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {

If (req.isAuthenticated ())
Return next ();

Res.redirect ('/login');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `return res.redirect` instead of `res.redirect` and tell me what happens. (same for render)

Also, what does the `console.log(req.session)` give you ?

Comment: With return the same happens = (, a console.log returns this when entering with a session Session {
   Cookie:
    {Path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      OriginalMaxAge: null,
      HttpOnly: true},
   Passport: {user: 1}}

Comment: That means `req.session` is not `null` or `undefined`, so you're not entering your redirect condition. But I guess you have tried and succeeded to enter the condition before ? You should add a console.log('Hello') before your `res.redirect` to check if you are indeed in there

Comment: 489/5000
I just checked and the problem is that it is not entering, the error of "Page is not properly redirecting" and the console only returns this GET / index 302 12,686 ms - 56
GET / index 302 2,300 ms - 56
GET / index 302 1,232 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.906 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.729 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.551 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.795 ms - 56
GET / index 302 1,430 ms - 56
GET / index 302 1,189 ms - 56
GET / index 302 2.079 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.706 ms - 56
GET / index 302 0.664 ms - 56

Comment: Thank you very much the solution was to put the si in the function islogged

Comment: How do you do that? I'm new here :( If you explain, I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

in passport, there is a inbuilt function, req.isAuthenticated()